# Task scheduler. How does it check for internet loss?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

How does task scheduler determine if a internet cconnection is lost? Just by losing connection to the wifi or actually by losing connection to the web? Im asking because ive setup a task with a script to reconnect triggerd by connection lost 10001 .. but sometimes the wifi connection itself stays active just no internet acces.

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager just shows the processes that are running and the details around these (process performance, users, app history, services) and does not monitor Internet Connectivity - that is not its job.

Likewise, Task Scheduler does not have a native Internet checking facility. There are scripts below for connecting and disconnecting wireless.

Assuming Windows 10, use the Internet icon in the System Tray and use the Network Troubleshooter if you are having issues. You can select which connection to troubleshoot in this dialogue.

For your question (sometimes the wifi connection itself stays active just no internet access) you need the Network Troubleshooter and you also need to look at your router to see if it is losing internet.

In Adapter Settings (Network and Sharing Center) you can look at the adapter and see what traffic is being processed. I use DU Meter for this.

*Follow up note based on input from the member asking the question:*

You can make a script / batch file to connect and disconnect the wireless.

Netsh Wlan Connect name="profile one"

Netsh Wlan Disconnect interface="profile one"

Use Nets Wlan  /? , Netsh Wlan Connect /? , and Netsh Wlan Disconnect /?  to see how these commands work.

You might be able to use PING to get an output for you. I am not sure about this.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I made a translation error . (English isn't native for me and windows therefore another language) What i meant is task scheduler. Further im connected to a hotspot that sometimes end up at "unknown network, no internet" according to windows 10. So somewhere goes something wrong and can't find the reason. The script activated by task scheduler when connection drops is a workaround so the system would reconnect and i can go outside home and the system will continue downloading game updates etc.

Comment: Task Scheduler will not check for Internet Loss either, unless you write an Internet Checking Program to include in the Task and give you an output.  I made some changes in my answer.

Comment: Ive already made a batch file for the reconnecting part. Which works great if the wifi connection itself drops. However in the rare occasion when the wifi stays connected but shows connected (unknown network no internet) this wont be adequate. Since task schedular only check for wifi disconnetion. Im not skilled enough for writing an Internet checking program (i think). So my best bet would be to make a batch run by task schuduler that pings periodicly to check the internet connectivity in conjunction with the reconnecting batch?  Additional info. I dont have physical acces to this hotspot.

Comment: task schedular can actualy start a task when wifi connection is lost actualy.

Comment: Did you try the NETSH commands in Task Scheduler (batch file)?